# If li has less than 3 characters, hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to be able to hide list items that have less than 3 characters, how do I do this? What is wrong with my code below?

I am a JavaScript/jQuery newbie.

```
jQuery().ready(function () {
    if (jQuery('ol li').length < 3) {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is saying

```
if (jQuery('ol li').length < 3) {  //If I have less than 3 li elements
    jQuery(this).hide();   //hide the window object
};
```

What you want to use is filter

```
$('ol li').filter( function(){ return $(this).text().length<3; } ).hide();
```

EDIT - Based on your comment in my post: If it is a span tag that could have other data around it:

```
$('ol li span').filter( function(){ return $(this).text().length<3; } ).parent().hide()
```

[Fiddle running the span example](http://jsfiddle.net/96DXy/)

Comment: This works, but what if I am trying to account for the characters within a span tag as well? But ultimately, I wanted to hide the entire li? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to filter out the elements that have a content of less than 3 characters, and hide those :

```
$(function() {
    $('ol li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().length < 3 ;
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: The filter definitely seems like the nicest way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length < 3)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FRHjg/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('ol li').filter(function(){ return $(this).text().length < 3; }).hide();
```

Another alternative could be this:

*(Because you are evaluating elements not value characters in your question code snippet)*

```
if($('ol li').length < 3){ $(this).hide(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the `.html()` of your DOM element and then do `.length` on that.